# Cross posting a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is it possible that this question about teaching torque is crossposted to the science educators Stack Exchange site? As a question I think it's great, just not fit for this particular site.

[The question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584479/)

Comment: There isn't any Stack Exchange site by the name *"Science Educators"*. The closest are *[Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/tour)*. Which one? As everybody knows, computer science is neither about computers nor about science.

Comment: I had the mathematics educators stack in mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd like the question *migrated*, please cast a custom moderator flag on the question.

The folks on Physics Meta can't really tell you what is and isn't okay to ask on a different Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 0):

> As a question I think it's great, just not fit for this particular site.

If you feel it is not a great fit on Physics SE then the proper course of action would probably be to close the question (or delete it) and post it in a site that is a better fit.

Cross posting is generally discouraged, but there are exceptions to things where common sense applies.  I would suggest that *if* you cross post then you should (ideally) link to the cross-posted question, explain briefly why you cross-posted and if an an answer is made that you feel is appropriate on the other site, link to it and close the question so we do not have unanswered questions sitting on the site.  Obviously that is fairly inconvenient to do, so it is best to avoid cross posting for your own sake as much as the rules.

Comment: Note that the PSE meta OP here didn't post the linked question.